# Periodicity of Fourier series's coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Why exactly continuous fourier-series's coefficients aren't periodic like coefficients of discrete transform (DFT)? $\exp(-j*2*\pi)$ is periodic in both sequences.

I understand in general, that continuous fourier-series's coefficients aren't periodic. But I'm asking a little bit deeper question. What exactly makes DFT coefficients periodic and continuous FS not periodic? Where is the reason?

Comment: Also asked on dsp.SE where it has already received one answer (by me).

Comment: try with $f(x) = 1_{x \in [0,1/2]}$ you get that $c_n = \int_0^{1} f(x) e^{-2i \pi n x} dx = \int_0^{1/2}  e^{-2i \pi n x} dx = \frac{e^{-2i \pi n x}}{-2i \pi n}|_0^{1/2} = \frac{e^{-i \pi n x}-1}{-2i \pi n}$ that isn't periodic. Now the discrete Fourier transform $X(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-2i \pi n k/N}$ is clearly $N$ periodic since $e^{-2i \pi n (k+N)/N} =e^{-2i \pi n k/N}e^{-2i \pi n N /N} = e^{-2i \pi n k/N}$